# Optimizing a specific regexp search for equidistant letters

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm working in Javascript but I think that's a general regexp question.

I'm writing a script which searches for substrings in a long string with equal distances between the letters. For example, in the text `a11b22c33d44` we have the string `abcd` with distance of 2 between every two consecutive letters.

It's trivial to find such strings using regexp search: for the example above, I just need to search for the regexp `/a.{2}b.{2}c.{2}d/`. So what I'm doing now is this: given a word to search and the distance between the consecutive letters I simply put `.{n}` between them (where n is the distance), compile this as a regexp and let it do the rest of the work.

This works very well in practice as long as the distance between letters is small - say, around 1000. Afterwards it becomes slow. It still works, but I hope there's another way to perform the same search more efficiently; I don't see an obvious reason why for larger gaps it should be significantly slower (we still need to go over the whole text only once, right?)

Comment: You example regexp `a.{2}b.{2}c.{2}d` would match `aaabbbcccd` as well -- is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, since aaabbbcccd still contains "abcd" as a substring with distance 2 between letters.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the dot can match almost anything, including letters.  Every time it finds an `a`, it has to gobble up the next *n* characters and try to match a `b` before giving up on that match.  That's a lot of wasted effort.

You need to be more specific about what you *don't* want to match.  For example, if your search terms will always consist entirely of letters, you can speed things up a lot by changing the `.` to `[^a-z]`

```
/a[^a-z]{1000}b[^a-z]{1000}c[^a-z]{1000}d/i
```

Another possibility is to match anything except the next required character:

```
/a[^b]{1000}b[^c]{1000}c[^d]{1000}d/i
```

Both solutions are based on the assumption that the text between the required characters can't contain the same characters.

Then again, if you're searching only for whole words, and you know the first and last characters of the search term will always be word characters, maybe you just need to add word boundaries:

```
/\ba.{1000}b.{1000}c.{1000}d\b/i
```

Comment: Thank you. The problem is that I can't assume there won't be letters in between (there almost surely will be).